# pandas extract latin words from multi language string to a separate column

Tags: pandas, split, python-re

I would like extract and store all latin words from multilingual string to separate column.
Desired output
'hhhh tcx cord\with plastic end / light mustard cm non woven grid socks'

I tried to use basic expression but it did not work

```
st={'string':['hhhh 15-0850tcx cord\with plastic end / light mustard -82cm  шнур нужд вес 07 кг','1. 06900000027899 non woven 12 grid socks']}
s = pd.DataFrame(st)
re.findall("[^a-zA-Z]", s)
```

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(st)

df['new'] = df['string'].str.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+")
print (df)
                                              string  \
0  hhhh 15-0850tcx cord\with plastic end / light ...   
1          1. 06900000027899 non woven 12 grid socks   

                                                 new  
0  [hhhh, tcx, cord, with, plastic, end, light, m...  
1                          [non, woven, grid, socks]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. What would be the code if I need non-English words?

Comment: Since my text half russian half inglish I found solution df['Ru_cleaned'] = df["string"].str.findall(r"[а-яА-Я]+") your code gave me a hint. Thanks